# No sound in android using Phaser

Tags: android, html5, phaser

I have developed a simple game using Phaser.  It's work perfect on ios webkit, but on android there is no sound.  What causes this problem on one platform but not the other?

We are using this code to load:

```
this.load.audio('game_audio', 'audio/bgm.mp3');
```

Playing:

```
this.music = this.add.audio('game_audio');
this.boom.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is almost certainly codec / sound format related, but without knowing how your `bgm.mp3` file is encoded it's really hard to tell. Maybe the encoding bitrate is too high, or the device can't handle mp3 files and needs ogg instead? You'll have to experiment I'm afraid as it's hard to say exactly from the post.